# Problem in getting time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

HI i need to increment 15 minutes in time intrval which i get in the webservice .
The code is as follows

```
        NSString *dateString =obj.String_date_start;   // start time is 2011-07-01 
    dateString = [dateString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ +0000",obj.String_time_start]];  //After this statement the date is 2011-07-01 03:00:00 +0000
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSDate *scheduledForYellow = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:900];
    [dateFormatter release];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

    NSString *strTime = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:scheduledForYellow]; 
    [dateFormatter1 release];
    NSArray *aryy = [strTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"end time ======>>>%@",[aryy objectAtIndex:1]);
    obj.String_StaticEndTime  = [aryy objectAtIndex:1];
```

Here to add 15 minutes to my start time i have written the above code , but in end time that is [aryy objectAtIndex:1] does not give me the correct time.What i wanted to do is increment 15 minutes for whatever date i get in start date .Dont know whats the issue is.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be because of the default timezone (local timezone) that the date formatter uses to generate the string. I have modified your code a bit to reuse the date formatter and fixed a leak with `dateFromString`.

```
NSString *dateString = obj.String_date_start;   // start time is 2011-07-01 
dateString = [dateString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ +0000",obj.String_time_start]];  //After this statement the date is 2011-07-01 03:00:00 +0000
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate * dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDate * scheduledForYellow = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:900];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString * strTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:scheduledForYellow]; 

NSArray * aryy = [strTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"end time ======>>>%@",[aryy objectAtIndex:1]);
obj.String_StaticEndTime  = [aryy objectAtIndex:1];
```

This should fix the issue. Let me know if you face any issues.